# Angular parent component render of HTML containing Angular code

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have an Angular parent component that makes an API call to obtain HTML content from CMS. But the CMS content has Angular code and needs to access parent scope's variables/events, e.g. this could be HTML need to be inserted into parent HTML template and rendered:

`const cmsHTML = "<div (click)="parentFunc()">{{parentVar}}</div>"`

Please help with how could I render this from the parent component.

I found that DomSanitizer can insert this HTML but it won't get compiled so everything here shows up as text. ng-content didn't seem to work also. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Try `<div [InnerHTML]="cmsHTML"></div>` to render content as HTML

Comment: That doesn't work since {{parentVar}} will be shown as text, not compiled.

Comment: Thats a poor practice, instead of HTML return JSON data try update the response.

Comment: I wish I could. Customer request need to have angular code inside HTML.

Comment: Then code like `{{parentVar}}` should also need to be present in component to render otherwise it will not have any value.